# How to extract slices (2D) from volume rendering (3D) in VTK?

Tags: c#, c++, vtk

Recently I started using VTK.
Volume rendering can be displayed using VTK's SimpleRayCast.
Next, I want to extract any slice (2D image) on that 3D.
I want to extract slices on a line in 3D data displayed by SimpleRayCast.

[image]

I think that it is necessary to combine with vtkImageReslice.
Is it possible to achieve it?